# API will sometimes return an empty dictionary in JSON Data instead of the usual float: how do I handle it? (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, api, dictionary

I am using an API to retrieve JSON Data and on occasion the API will give me an empty dictionary when it usually gives me a float or nil If the float is 0.

It seems it is doing this when the value should be nil

How do I handle this? Is there a way so if I am given this empty dictionary value I can just ignore it or return nil or even 0?

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the API (preferred approach), then you can use an `enum` with associated values representing each type of result.

So, for the sake of example, let's assume that you get the following two types of results:

Success case:

```
{ "value": 5.2 }
```

Failure case:

```
{ "value": {} }
```

Then you can decode this with an enum, like so:

```
enum Result: Decodable {
   case success(Float)
   case error
    
   enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case value }
    
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
      if let value = try? container.decodeIfPresent(Float.self, forKey: .value) {
         self = .success(value)
      } else {
         self = .error
      }
   }
}
```

You can then decode and extract the number:

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: json)

if case let .success(value) = result {
    print(value) // 5.2
}
```